Kotlin unit test suspend function "android.os.Looper.getMainLooper()" is null
I tried to test a suspend function got the error:
Cannot invoke "android.os.Looper.getThread()" because the return value of "android.os.Looper.getMainLooper()" is null

 class HomeViewModelTest {
    @Test
    fun settingMainDispatcher() = runTest {
        val testDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)

        try {
            //My test code is here
            myMethod()

        } finally {
            Dispatchers.resetMain()
        }
    }
}

suspend fun myMethod() {
   withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        errorLiveData.value = errorMessage
   }
}

Android Studio Version: Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1

If this is coming from Dispatchers.resetMain(), do you need to call that? It would be better if myMethod() took its dispatcher as a parameter, rather than hard-coding Dispatchers.Main, as then you would not need to setMain() and resetMain() in the first place.

I think the source of error is assigning the value to the LiveData. To confirm that just replace it with errorLiveData.postValue. In general for LiveData testing you will need InstantTaskExecutorRule.
